# Problems with Swift3: cannot understand new syntax

Tags: xcode, swift3, ios10, nsurlsessiondatatask, xcode8.2

Yesterday I updated to Xcode 8.2 which forced me to update to Swift 3.0 syntax. In my app I have this function:

```
func performGetRequest(_ targetURL: URL!, completion:@escaping (_ data: Data?, _ HTTPStatusCode: Int, _ error: NSError?) -> Void)
{
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: targetURL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    let Session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

    let tasksession = Session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if data != nil{
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            completion(data: data, HTTPStatusCode: (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error: error)})
        }
        else
        {
            print("Connection Lost")
        }

    })
    tasksession.resume()
}
```

**And I get this error:**

> Cannot invoke 'dataTask' with an argument list of type '(with: NSMutableURLRequest, completionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void)'

Please, would someone help me to correct it?

Comment: Xcode 8.2 doesn't force you to update to Swift 3.0, you can still use Swift 2.3. But Xcode 8.3 will force you to move to Swift 3.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Swift 3 it is batte if you check `Apple Documentation`, Now [`dataTask(with:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask) will take [`URLRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlrequest) as first argument and the `completionHandler` is changed to `(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void`. So make instance of `URLRequest` instead of `NSMutableURLRequest` and made changes of `completionHandler` also. In Swift 3 with most of the public API they have changed `NSError` to [`Error`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/error). So batter if you use `Error` too.

```
func performGetRequest(_ targetURL: URL!, completion:@escaping (_ data: Data?, _ HTTPStatusCode: Int, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {

    let request = URLRequest(url: targetURL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    let Session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

    let tasksession = Session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if data != nil{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(data: data, HTTPStatusCode: (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error: error)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("Connection Lost")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(data: nil, HTTPStatusCode: (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error: error)
            }
        }

    }
    tasksession.resume()
}
```

**Note:** You need to call your `completionHendler` with all possible ways, you haven't called it when you are receiving `nil` data you need to call it inside the else block also with `nil` as data value.

**Edit:** You can call this function like this.

```
self.performGetRequest(url) { (data, status, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    //Use data here
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nirav D so much for your help but i have another problem how can i call this function performGetRequest
Thanks again

Comment: @bero Currently Mac is not available, will help you tomorrow.

Comment: Okay no problem I'm waiting you and Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @bero Check the edited answer for how you call this function.

Comment: Thanks so much it's work

Comment: @bero Welcome mate :)